# Play with Activator Issue on IntelliJ Idea 14

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

I have the following problem on IntelliJ IDEA 14:

I created a Play (Scala) project using the Activator (v1.2.10). Then, I converted it to an IDEA project using `activator idea` command. When, I opened the project with **IDEA 14** (Community Edition) the SBT module is not enabled. Therefore, a new dependency in build.sbt file is not included in the classpath. Moreover, the project is not listed in IDEA's SBT view.

The following warning is shown by IDEA:

"*This IDEA project is converted from an SBT project by gen-idea tool, which currently relies on a legacy Scala project model. Please consider using built-in SBT support via the Import project action.*"

Note that, the Scala and SBT plugins are already installed on IDEA.

I *don't* encounter with the same issue in IDEA 13.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `File | Import Project` and select `build.sbt` file?

IDEA imports it as an `SBT` project, with all the dependencies properly resolved. It works fine for me on IDEA 14 and on 13.

Comment: Unfortunately not working. Might it be about the community edition of IDEA?

Comment: If you're having trouble with the SBT support in IntelliJ, a work-around for now is, when you've added a new dependency, to use `reload` and then `idea` in the activator console.  IntelliJ will then detect the changes to the project files and request a refresh.

Comment: @ovunccetin Scala and SBT support [should be available](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) in the Community version.  But Play support is only in Ultimate.

Comment: Play support has been moved into the Scala plugin. Shouldn't that make it available in the Community version?

Comment: @Splaktar According to the [Intellij IDEA Editions Comparison Matrix](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) I linked above, play support is not available on Community Edition.

Comment: I see a down-vote on my answer, can you please add a comment to explain why you down-voted?

Comment: Well we have people here using Play with the Community version right now 

Comment: @Splaktar Sorry, I did not mean to say that Play projects will not work with Intellij Community version, I was just responding to the first comment here. I haven't had a chance to test it with Community edition, only info I had was the official statement from JetBrains.

Comment: Should import work if we're using `project/Build.scala` instead of `build.sbt`? IDEA can't seem to figure out what JVM or SDK to use.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is a bug in some versions of IntelliJ 14, that *just* got fixed (as of version 14.0.3). Updating IJ then updating the scala plugin seems to make things work.

Answer (score 0):

In this case simply import manually the "build.sbt" from your project, so if the directory is ~/Documents/myPlayApp then choose to import ~/Documents/myPlayApp/build.sbt